# How to remove the leaflet L.control.watermark from the map

Tags: leaflet, mapcontrol

I tried to add a picture to the map by using a button. This works well by using L.control.watermark. But I want to remove the picture at the next button click and I can´t find a working solution. 
Here is what I tried so far:

```
pictureActive = false;

showPicture() {
            if (!this.pictureActive) {
                this.displayPicture(true);
                this.pictureActive = true;
                this.pictureStyle.backgroundColor = "#002896"; //buttonStyle

            }
            else {
                this.displayPicture(false);
                this.pictureActive = false;
                this.pictureStyle.backgroundColor = "#999999";
            }
        },

displayPicture(active){
            console.log('displayPicture');
            if (active) {
                L.Control.Watermark = L.Control.extend({
                    onAdd: function(map) {
                        var img = L.DomUtil.create('img');

                        img.src = 'BUGAlog.png';
                        img.style.width = '200px';

                        return img;
                    },

                    onRemove: function(map) {
                    }
                });
                L.control.watermark = function(opts) {
                    return new L.Control.Watermark(opts);
                };
                L.control.watermark({ position: 'topright' }).addTo(this.map);
            } else {
                this.map.removeControl(L.control.watermark);
            }
        },
```

or:

```
else {
   L.control.watermark.removeFrom(self.map);;
}
```

But the picture stays...

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can put class definition and create function definition out of show/hide logic:

```
L.Control.Watermark = L.Control.extend({
    onAdd: function(map) {
        var img = L.DomUtil.create('img');

        img.src = 'baseball-marker.png';
        img.style.width = '50px';

        return img;
    },

    onRemove: function(map) {
    }
});
L.control.watermark = function(opts) {
    return new L.Control.Watermark(opts);
};
```

Then define global `var` for your control:

```
var myControl;
```

And then your display/hide function looks like:

```
displayPicture(active){
    if (active) {
        myControl = L.control.watermark({ position: 'topright' }).addTo(map);
    } else {
        map.removeControl(myControl);
    }
}
```